# Extracting vectors from list in R without looping

Tags: r

This is probably a very simple question, however I have googled for hours without a satisfying answer. Let's suppose I have a list like the following one:

```
theList <- list(c("de", "labore", "solis"), c("sapiento", "post", "eventum"), c("sursum", "corda"))

> theList
[[1]]
[1] "de"     "labore" "solis" 

[[2]]
[1] "sapiento" "post"     "eventum" 

[[3]]
[1] "sursum" "corda"
```

If I want to print all the vectors that compose the list I would think of something like

```
for(i in 1:length(theList)) {
  print(theList[[i]])
}

[1] "de"     "labore" "solis" 
[1] "sapiento" "post"     "eventum" 
[1] "sursum" "corda"
```

however there must be a more elegant solution, probably using some member of the apply family...

Comment: Do you just want `unlist(theList)`? Or maybe `invisible(sapply(theList, print))`. Is it just a matter of formatting?

Comment: Afraid not; I want to visit each vector in the list and do something with it (printing in this example), while preserving the list

Comment: That makes things even less clear. What exactly do you need the code to do? I've shown an `sapply` example. I just use `invisible()` to suppress the default return value since you were just printing.

Comment: Then l`apply` and `sapply` are the obvious answers. What text are you using to learn R? ... or are you just using the "hammer and hope" strategy?

Answer (score -1):

I think I got an answer after doing some more googling and experimenting...

```
extract <- function(m) {
  sapply(seq_along(m), function(x) m[[x]])
}

> extract(theList)
[[1]]
[1] "de"     "labore" "solis" 

[[2]]
[1] "sapiento" "post"     "eventum" 

[[3]]
[1] "sursum" "corda"
```

So it would be a matter of performing the desired operation (e.g. printing) on the result from the `sapply`

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but how is this output different from the original `theList`?

Comment: Just so we're clear: your `extract` function literally did nothing. It took a list and simply returned the list back. Nothing more (aside from a bunch of looping that accomplished nothing).

Comment: Apologies if I did not make myself clear enough: the idea is to access each of the vectors that comprise the list in a list[[i]] fashion and perform some operation on each of them (printing was a simple example, but for example I could have wanted to get rid of all vowels in each vector), but without having to use a for loop

Comment: Sorry, downvoting because this is not the right way to do anything in R, and so is not a beneficial Q&A for future visitors. To illustrate with your example, you should do `rid_vowels <- function(x) gsub("[aeiou]","",x)` and then `sapply(theList,rid_vowels)`

Comment: ...and you should read carefully about both `sapply` and `lapply` before leaping to the conclusion that one of them is right for your use case.